# redirect_uri_mismatch - asp.net-core with google calendar api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-calendar-api

I want to test my asp.net core 3.1 app that uses the google caledar api:

Running my app on localhost I receive an error message from google when I try to login via google:

*"The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:57695/authorize/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs"*

I have checked the following:

launchsettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53936",
      "sslPort": 44376
    }
  }
```

credentials.json

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "***",
    "project_id": "***",
    "auth_uri": "***",
    "token_uri": "***",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "***",
    "client_secret": "***",
    "redirect_uris": [ "https://localhost:44376/Success" ],
    "javascript_origins": [ "https://localhost:44376" ]

  }
}
```

Settings in the developer console:

Authorized Java-Script sources:
https://localhost:44376

Authorized redirect URIs:
https://localhost:44376/Success

As far as I can judge that, the URI mentioned in the error message (http://127.0.0.1:57695/authorize/) is defined nowhere inside my application.

Comment: "localhost" is a shorthand to "127.0.0.1" and it seems that your browser is replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1", try to change the authorized URI to be "127.0.0.1".

Comment: In addition to what Guzman said, see also [RFC 8252, section 8.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252#section-8.3) which states that localhost is not recommended for a redirect URI, and that the loopback IP address, i.e. 127.0.0.1, should be used.

Comment: Are you modifying in any way the ```credentials.json``` file you get for interfacing the Calendar API?

Comment: @ese_zeta, did you ever get this figured out? If so, can you post the answer. I am trying to do this and having the same issue. So much documentation but not a ton of useful/helpful stuff.